# Weblogic 12c - Handling Datasource error at startup

Tags: weblogic, startup

I have configured different datasources in Weblogic 12c. Out of three configured datsource,  i dont want to have connectivity test setup during application/server start? to handle same. I tried configuring the initial capacity to 0 for that particular DS. It's not working. Can someone suggest if I am missing something or any other suggestion/way to handle same via configuration?

Comment: if  at least one datasource cannot connect to its database during startup, the server starts in admin mode. If you need to ignore datasource failure and start your server in RUNNING mode you can use the following jvm property : -Dweblogic.deployment.IgnorePrepareStateFailures=true

Comment: Is there a way if I can ignore any one datasource instead of all?

Comment: it is not possible, its all or nothing.