# Creating two generic data sources in weblogic 11g with one data source URL working another data source URL is not working

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

This requirement is for weblogic multi data source creation.

I have to create multiple data source in weblogic 11g  with two generic data sources, however one data source listener is down and only one db listener is working.

I configured two data sources but when i start the weblogic server getting exception for down database data source. How can i disable checking data source is working or not in weblogic. I set

> initial-capacity = 0
>
> global-transactions-protocol = one phase commit

above case working but same for

> initial-capacity = 0
>
> global-transactions-protocol = logging last resource

transaction type logging last resource case not working.

Comment: Can you try selecting Failover algorithm for the MultiData Source and try? For LLR, Database must be available while starting Weblogic Server.

Comment: Check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915445/weblogic-12c-handling-datasource-error-at-startup